# Logisim full adder output unknown

Tags: digital-logic, adder

So I was implementing a 16-bit square root function using [this algorithm](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/91040a.pdf).

The components contains several 8-bit multipliers and 16-bit comparators, with gates addressing the cycle mechanism mentioned in the algorithm. Here's the highest level schematic:

[image]

All ARGs are exactly the same (The first one looks a bit large, but still the same):
[image]

On the top right is a 16-bit comparator, nothing wrong with it. The error is in the lower left 8-bit multiplier.

[image]

As you can see, one of the output wire is red, indicating some errors.

It turns out that it was from one of the full adder in the 8-bit multiplier, as such:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

**How come the output of that particular Full Adder becomes blue(unkown)?**

After I investigate that full adder, all its wires are blue, which makes little sense to me, since its inputs aren't unknown at all!

[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9uaupz7a2idcf0/CAS.circ?dl=0) is the circuit file.

Comment: Can you share your .circ file somewhere? And, as an aside: Is there some reason you aren't using bus wires anywhere?

Comment: The Cin seem to be unknown if I understand correctly the last drawing. Is it connected?

Comment: @duskwuff  Just added my .circ file. Oh, I was just not aware that bus is allowed in logisim..

Comment: @EugeneSh., yes it is connected. From the second last image you can see that its cin is green. I assume it is a bug as rfoster said..

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a similar bug in the past when working with logisim. Try saving the file, closing it, and reopening it. That should solve the problem with the misbehaving full adder.

Comment: Another thing to try is "reset simulation".